# Placement of period in sentence that ends with "et al." followed by reference number?

Tags: citations, grammar

I have a citation that is at the end of a sentence with dual punctuation. What I mean is that I have a sentence of the following form:

> Blah blah blah is mentioned by Author et al.

What is the proper way to include the citation in this case?

1. > Blah blah blah is mentioned by Author et al[##].
2. > Blah blah blah is mentioned by Author et al.[##]
3. > Blah blah blah is mentioned by Author et al.[##].
4. Other

Comment: Related (on [english.se]): [Can there be two consecutive dots at the end of the sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91631/can-there-be-two-consecutive-dots-at-the-end-of-the-sentence) and [When “etc.” is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I believe this is a grammar issue, *not* a style issue.

Comment: @ff524 different styles have different ways to cite such issue.

Comment: Whatever you do, put a space (ideally, a protected one) before “[##]”.

Comment: I'd use 3 (but with a space before [##] as @Wrzlprmft said).  The abbreviation "et al." deserves a period, and the end of the sentence deserves a period; as long as there's something between those two periods, I'd use them both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since "et al." is an abbreviation of the latin *et alii* meaning "and others" the period in "et al." should be treated as periods in any other abbreviation such as "cf.", "Op. Cit.", "conf.", "c.". In most cases of which I am aware periods are shown after abbreviations but I am not a stranger to styles where the period after abbreviations are ignored. So my bet is that "et al. [##]." or "et al. [##]", depending on where the preferred location of the numbered references are, in a majority of cases. If you are uncertain you need to consult the journal style sheet (if any exists) or simply check other recent papers published by the journal in order to see how they prefer to have things set.

Comment: Between "Author et al. proposed that sky is blue [4]." and "Author et al. [1] proposed that sky is blue.", which one is preferrable?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq A matter of style but having the number associated with the location of the names seems preferable. So your second example.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the publisher's style guide. If the style calls for the use of periods after "et al." or other such expressions, then you should use them, independent of whether the reference forces an additional period. if the guidelines don't ask for one, don't use it.

Comment: Is there any style that *doesn't* use a period after et al.? I thought this is a matter of correctness, not style ("et al." stands for "et alia" - "al." is an abbreviation, so it gets a period)

Comment: @ff524 I think [AMA](http://library.nymc.edu/informatics/amastyle.cfm) does not use a period after "et al." for in text citations, but does use a period in the reference list.

Comment: @ff524: Journals published in the UK will also likely not use periods.

Answer (score 0):

> 4. Other

Two other possibilities are the followings:

4a. "Blah blah blah is mentioned in [##]". This is ok since you are using numeric citations.

4b. "Blah blah blah is mentioned by Author *et al.* in [##]"

Comment: I didn't think you could use numeric citations as a noun, I thought the sentence had to be intelligible without the number.

Comment: @StrongBad: I've found the above usage fairly common, but I can't cite any reference supporting it (nor one against it, though). At least, no editor/reviewer ever corrected me on this :-) Yet another possibility is to rephrase completely the sentence as "As mentioned by Author _et al._ [##], blah blah blah."

Comment: That's an example of different conventions in different fields. In Math and some areas of CS, it's standard that references can act as objects in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Blah blah blah is mentioned by Author et al. [##].

(Note the space before the brackets; whether there is "et al." or not makes no difference here.)

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE referencing guide can be found  [here](http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/gettingstarted) for those seeking IEEE specific referencing instructions.

Answer (score -2):

**Another *other:***

> Blah blah blah is mentioned in Ref. [##].

At least this is what is used by all journals using a numeric citation style that I am aware of.

Comment: Not all journals allow abbreviations like "Ref.", probably only those that allow abbreviations like Fig. or Tab. If I were to write for an IEEE journal I'd probably write "Blah blah blah is mentioned in Ref. [##]", but for some IOP journals "Blah blah blah is mentioned in [##]" seems more common.